# I need help on creating columns with aggregations

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following problems are based on the tables presented below where users have certain transactions. Keep in mind that the primary key of the Users table is on both the User ID and Site ID columns.

Users

```
User ID Site ID     Name
1        1          Arthur
2        1          Aaron
2        2          Brett
```

Transactions

```
Transaction ID  User ID Site ID Transaction Type    Transaction Date  Amount
4                  1       1         Sale              1/1/2017         120
6                  1       1         Refund            1/7/2017       -120
7                  2       2         Sale              1/5/2017         90
9                  2       1         Sale              12/1/2016        30
10                 2       1         Sale              1/1/2017         30
11                 2       1         Sale              2/1/2017         30
12                 2       1         Refund            2/7/2017 

   [enter image description here][1]-30
```

> Write a query that will return a table with the following columns:
>   User ID, Site ID, User Name, Total Sales, Total Refunds, Net Amount Collected

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: "Write a query that..." Sounds like homework. Well, if we do it for you, you won't learn much.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Short of writing your query for you, I would use a `CASE WHEN` statment to get my sums.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query below.

```
SELECT 
  t.UserId,
  t.SiteId,
  u.Name,
  sum(IIF(transaction_type = 'Sale', 1, 0) * isnull(Amount,0)) totalSales,
  sum(IIF(transaction_type = 'Refund', 1, 0) * isnull(Amount,0)) totalRefunds,
  sum(isnull(amount, 0)) NetAmount
From Transactions t
inner join Users u
  on u.UserId = t.UserId and u.SiteId = t.siteId
Group by
  t.UserId,
  t.SiteId,
  u.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.site_id,
    u.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'Sale' THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) total_sale,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'Refund' THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) total_refund,
    SUM(t.amount) total
FROM
    users AS u
    INNER JOIN transactions AS t
        ON  t.user_id = u.user_id
        AND t.site_id = u.site_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_id,
    u.site_id,
    u.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was my homework question, I would add an overall total as well.

```
SELECT  
     t.UserID
    ,t.SiteID
    ,u.Name
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'Sale' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS tsales
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'Refund' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS trefunds
    ,SUM(t.Amount) AS Total
FROM Transactions t
JOIN Users u ON u.SiteID = t.SiteID
             AND u.UserID = t.UserID
GROUP BY 
     t.UserID
    ,t.SiteID
    ,u.Name
UNION
SELECT  
     999 AS UserId
    ,999 AS SiteID
    ,'TOTALS:' AS [Name]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'Sale' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS tsales
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'Refund' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS trefunds
    ,SUM(t.Amount) AS Total
FROM Transactions t
```

This will get a result that looks like this:

[image]

**Note: I didn't think ahead and make the two ID columns Varchar, my easy fix was the 999 that you see to keep the order I wanted.**